# How to upload multiple jar files into Azure through VSTS using Azure App service deploy task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

how to deploy multiple jar files into Azure through  VSTS using Azure App service deploy task.Currently I am deploying War files using azure app service deploy task but I am not able to deploy jar files.Its throwing the error.The task name is:Azure app service deploy.I tried to deploy using this pattern:$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/project_name/drop/*.jar and $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/project_name/drop/jarfile.jar

I am running the azure app service deploy task at the time of release definition.

Both patterns not working.throwing error.

So can anyone please help me out how to accomplish this task?

Errors:

Error getting when I am giving the below pattern in package or folder option in azure app service deploy task in VSTS.

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/project_name/drop/*.jar

Error:
More than one package matched with specified pattern. Please restrain the search pattern.


Error getting when I am giving the below pattern in package or folder option in azure app service deploy task in VSTS.

$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/project_name/drop/jarfile.jar


 [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='d:\a\r1\a\project_name\drop\direcotry1\target\jarfile.jar' -dest:contentPath='abc-dev',ComputerName='https://abc-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=abc-dev',UserName='********',Password='********',AuthType='Basic' -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -userAgent:VSTS_f2463a61-0e8b-4b3a-841d-15b916aae127_release_4_236_570_1
2017-11-02T11:12:56.6532444Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2017-11-02T11:12:56.6542438Z ##[error]Error: Package file 'd:\a\r1\a\project_name\drop\direcotry1\target\jarfile.jar' does not have a .zip file name extension.
Error count: 1.
```

Pleas help me on this..How to give the pattern to upload multiple jar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck **Publish using Web Deploy** option in **Additional Deployment options** section of **Azure App Service Deploy** task, then specify the folder path in **Package or folder** input box.

[image]

Update:

[image]

If there are some files in that folder that you don’t want to deploy to azure app services, you can copy necessary files to another folder through [Copy File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files) tasks

Update:

[image]

Comment: Hi MSFT, The publish using web deploy option already unchecked.I have  3 folders and 4 script files.among which I need to deploy only 3 jar files located in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/project_name/drop/folder1/jar1.jar            $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/project_name/drop/folder2/jar2.jar      $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/project_name/drop/folder3/jar3.jar       I want to copy the above 3 jars only and don't want to copy other script files and folders inside drop folder.

Comment: HI MSFT, Can you reply on my request please.

Comment: HI MSFT, I need to deploy to azure app service under /site/libs..for that I need to add subscription right.so usually I am selecting the subscription part and deploying the war files but here jars files need to deploy right.whatever you have replied that is for to copy into deploy folder but I wan to deploy into kudu azure portal under this location /site/libs..one more thing I have many other jar files in the libs folder.I don't want to delete those jar files.Just need to remove the jar1,jar2,jar3 files under site/libs and need to deploy latest jars.But don't wanto to delete other jars in lib

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN By default, the app service folder is site\wwwroot, do you change it to site\libs? Provide the detail setting of Visual application and directories. (Select app service in azure portal=> Application settings). On the other hand, the copy files task is used to copy files, you also need to add App service deploy task to publish files to azure.

Comment: Yes,I need to deploy to site/libs folder.Under application settings I could  see :   /         site\wwwroot    Application...this line only configured under virtual applications and directories.I am using app service deploy task only but don't know how to deploy multiple jar files to azure.that's why asked you the pattern.please help me.

Comment: On the other hand how to send screen shot via comment box .

Comment: Simple steps: 1. Add a new virtual applications in azure portal (e.g. lib, site\libs, check Application option) 2. Copy files task to copy files to DeployFolder 3. Azure app service (Virtual application: lib; Package or folder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\DeployFolder; Uncheck Publish using Web Deploy option)

Comment: Can I have the 2nd step details of copy files task?Why do we need copy files task as we are using azure app service right.

Comment: Because, you just can specify a folder in Azure App service deploy task, and the Copy files task just used to copy necessary files to another folder.

Comment: so after copy task we need to run app service deploy task right ? and in copy  files task its asking for target folder what should I give? and in app service deploy task ,under virtual  application I have given lib.its failing.   error: ##[error]Error: Virtual application doesn't exists : lib

Comment: @MSFT, Now I have removed all the scripts.Now I have only 3 jar's inside drop folder.Now I could able to deploy 3 files into azure but those 3 jar's are going to /site/wwwroot location as part of azure app service deploy.So I have run mv command to move those 3 jars into site/libs folder.Now its throwing error saying that device is busy ,can't move.Even I changed the virtual application& directory settings in azure application settings as you suggested like /site/libs.but throwing error device is busy.

Comment: @PDBRPRAVEEN Yes, you need to to run app service deploy task after copy task. Regarding Virtual application doesn't exists, you need to check Application option for lib virtual application in azure portal. (Do not need to deploy to site/wwwroot)

Comment: @MSFT, Can you please tell me clearly,currently in azureportal under application settings, I keep this setting:under virtual applications and directories:I put virtual directory: / and physical path relative to site: site/libs and application  option marked (check box checked).Previously existed row which is pointing to site/wwwroot row I removed and added new line to point to site/libs I could see physical path relative to site: site/wwwroot this row I removed.So tell me what should I change here.

Comment: How to attach screen shot via comment box.

Comment: Currently as I told you,I have configured my release def,under app service deploy task: 1.package or folder option: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/abc/Artifacts -so as per this step the 3 jar's directly going to site/wwwroot 2.inline script I am trying to move those 3 jars from site/wwwroot to site/libs.But its throwing device busy error.Tell me what changes I need to do.

Comment: tell me what changes I need to do in azure portal with screen shots if possible.

Comment: Now, Its copying 3 jar's into site/libs folder only when I am using mv command or copy command at the same time its throwing the error like can't recognize copy-item command can't recognize mv command.But its copying and throwing error.if I don't use any inline script then its not copying anything.so what I did is I have put inline script as  cd D:\home\site\libs.then its copying jars and as well as not throwing any error.shall I go ahead with this approach.

Comment: You don't need to remove the default application, check the update of my answer. Does inline script mean PowerShell task inline script? You just can call Kudu API to copy files, can do it through PowerShell task.

Comment: no,I am not using any powershell task.Inline script is in built in task available in azure app service deploy task..I am running the command like cd D:\home\site\libs..that's it.by running this command in inline script,I don't see any errors.as per your comments how to call kudu api..using call https://abc-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net/ or how to call?

Comment: If you deploy the files to site/wwwroot folder, then the current context of script is in site/wwwroot, so you can use this command instead: `copy *.jar ..\libs /y`

Comment: @MSFT, The only change required to copy jars are adding the virtual directory as lib and point to /site/libs in azure.That's it.Its copying all the jars inside the drop folder.No inline script is required now.This is resolved now..Thanks again for your help throughout this task.I will accept your answer.Keep supporting me always.